# Program displays the highest value but it does not display the person with the highest value

Tags: java, arrays

i am able to output the highest value but i cant seem to get it to work when i do .getNames as it shows me an error

the error is that i cant seem to display the associated name with its highest value it only displays the balance

```
    //Highest Balance
    Double largest = customer[0].getBalance();

    for (int i=0; i<customer.length; i++)
    {
        if(customer[i].getBalance() > largest) 
            largest = customer[i].getBalance(); 

    }
    System.out.println("The highest balance is " + largest);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to store the name associated to the highest value. You can either update it when you update the `largest` balance, or you can store the entire `customer` object that holds the largest value (and the largest balance). Example:

```
Double largest = customer[0].getBalance();
String name = "";

for (int i=0; i<customer.length; i++)
{
     if(customer[i].getBalance() > largest) 
     {
            largest = customer[i].getBalance();
            name = customer[i].getName();
      }
 }
 System.out.println("The highest balance is " + largest);
 System.out.println("The name of the customer is " + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your class there must be a method `getName()` or something similar, like the `getBalance()` method:

```
Double largest = customer[0].getBalance();
String name = customer[0].getName();
for (int i = 1; i < customer.length; i++) {
    if(customer[i].getBalance() > largest) { 
        largest = customer[i].getBalance(); 
        name =  = customer[i].getName(); 
    }
}
System.out.println("The highest balance is " + largest);
System.out.println("The customer with highest balance is " + name);
```

Also you can start the loop from the 2nd array item (position = 1) since you already have assigned the values of the 1st item (position = 0) to `largest` and `name`.